# Weird problems when switching partitions on a PC dual-booting Win10 and Debian

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, debian, multi-boot

I've recently set up Debian on a partition on my laptop, and I am having a few very strange, but consistent, unexpected behaviors.

1. The first is that the clock on my Windows partition is wrong every time I boot up after booting into Debian.
2. The second is that the WiFi on Windows is always broken after I have loaded up Debian (I am using the non-free iwlwifi drivers on Debian). It always works after I fully disable the wireless network adapter and re-enable. Also during startup, error messages from Debian suggest it has some difficulty loading the network interface (though it always works on startup).

Anyway, obviously neither of these problems are crippling because there is an obvious solution (sync the system clock and reset the network adapter), but I'm wondering if there's some kind of configuration problem that could cause issues down the line and would prefer to address it now.

Answer (score 3):

> The first is that the clock on my Windows partition is wrong every time I boot up after booting into Debian.

Windows traditionally expects the hardware RTC to store local time (i.e. with timezone offset applied) while Linux prefers UTC time. See this article on changing Windows to interpret it as UTC:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_time#UTC_in_Windows

(Both OSes internally work with UTC, so using the same for the RTC avoids daylight-savings related problems. You can however do the opposite and change Debian to expect local time.)

> The second is that the WiFi on Windows is always broken after I have loaded up Debian (I am using the non-free iwlwifi drivers on Debian).

Check if you have any updates to linux-firmware or a newer kernel branch (linux-image), e.g. from Debian backports repository, and check whether there are any updates for the Windows driver on Intel's own website.

Failing that, create a "service" on Debian that powers off the entire Wi-Fi adapter at PCI device level during shutdown, forcing Windows to reinitialize it anew. It might work.